# c# Cannot add rows to gridview (error:missing some reference)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying simply to add some rows to a gridview. My straight code is as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       GridView1.Rows.A //(and here the intellisense does not give me help)

    }
}
```

if i force the intellisense the vs complains about a missing directive

Comment: this looks like asp.net? If so, there is not .Add() method. You can either set the datasource to a datatable and modify that then rebind it or you might try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.createrow.aspx

Comment: `Rows` is a collection, have you tried to access by index, for instace: `GridView1.Rows[0]` ?

Comment: So In brief the answer is I cannot do it simple and straight?

Comment: Correct. I would set the GridView1.DataSource to a Datatable, do all the modification to that, and then just simply databind the gridview.

Comment: I removed the comment and made an answer with a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach to use in a GridView would be to use its source instead of directly adding rows. Create a System.Data.DataTable, set it to the GridView1.DataDource and add rows to the table.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetTable;
}
static DataTable GetTable()
{ 
// Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
// Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
    return table;
}
```